# when does a byte_order change gets ignored?

Tags: c

I get a warning for a function's argument that typecasting here is changing byte_order from bigendian int to int. so I change it to bigendian int. but doing this gets ignored.

`function_call_name((int*)&argument1, argument2));`

`function_call_name((int* __attribute__((bigendian))) & argument1, argument2);`

Tried to find solution for this 
https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/628908

But things are not working out.

Can I get some help? :)

Also, how to know what byte_order is running. I mean some #ifdef directive?

Comment: What type is `argument1`?

Comment: the web page you linked has all the details AND has examples including how to declare a function that uses a non-default 'endian' byte ordering.  What are you doing that the byte ordering is even a consideration?

Comment: @4386427 argument 1 is of type size_t and the function is like

`function ( int * param1, char* param2);`

Comment: Hi, @user3629249, I also used

`int __attribute__((bigendian)) *  instead of int * attribute__((bigendian)) ` as the page suggested but that is also getting ignored.

It might not be for type-casting then.

Comment: I think you should mention the compiler you are working with. Because `__attribute__` is certainly not standard C (as you have tagged) and not portable.

Comment: Could it be that this is **not** to be used when calling the function but when declaring the function? Like `void foo(int* __attribute__((bigendian)) param1, char* param2);`

Comment: Can you please put some actual codes and errors?

Answer (score 0):

If those (non-standard) qualifiers are anything like the `const` qualifier, for example, then:

```
const int *a;                 // a is a pointer to const int
int const *b;                 // b is a pointer to int const (same as a)
int * const c = (int[42]){0}; // c is a const pointer to int (DIFFERENT!)
```

The differences to these can be observed by trying to modify them:

```
a = (int const[]){0}; // This is allowed
a[0] = 42;            // This is NOT allowed
c = NULL;             // This is NOT allowed
c[0] = 42;            // This is allowed
```

---

I think you probably meant to write `int __attribute__((bigendian)) *`, i.e. putting the attribute *before* the asterisk to denote that you wanted a *pointer to big endian `int`*, because putting it *after* would denote a *big endian pointer to `int`*...